# correctly fixing conversion and loss of data warnings?

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-warnings

I have a class called `PointF` and it has a constructor that takes a `Point`, and I keep getting "possible loss of data warnings". How can I show that my intention is in fact to make a `float` value into an `int`, among other tings? I tried `static_cast` and `(float)` but they did not fix the warning.

For example:

```
int curPos = ceil(float(newMouseY / font.getLineHeight())) ; //float to int
```

And

```
outputChars[0] = uc; //converting from size_t to char
```

Comment: Please add some example code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cast should do the trick; that says "explicitly make this type into that type", which is generally pretty silly for a compiler to warn for:

```
int curPos = static_cast<int>(ceil(float(newMouseY / font.getLineHeight())));
```

Or:

```
outputChars[0] = static_cast<char>(uc);
```

Make sure the casts you tried were akin to that. You say "I tried ...`(float)`" which leads me to believe you tried something like this:

```
int curPos = (float)(ceil(float(newMouseY / font.getLineHeight())));
```

Which does nothing. The type of the expression is already a `float`, what would casting it to the same type do? You need to cast it to the destination type.

---

Keep in mind casts are generally to be avoided. In your first snippet, the cast is sensible because when you quantize something you necessarily need to drop information.

But your second cast is not. Why is `uc` a `size_t` in the first place? What happens when the cast *does* drop information? Is that really a good idea?

Comment: that would never happen though:
 if (uc <= 0x7f) {
   outputChars[0] = static_cast<char>(uc);
   return 1;
  }

Comment: @Milo: Okay, the check is a valid solution, though `0x7f` is a pretty magical number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of `ceil`, preferably with a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to use an explicit cast, i.e.

int curPos = int(ceil(...));

Answer (score 0):

You must cast your variable to normally good way change type of her. And if you trying convert `size_t` to `char`, then you trying save `4 bytes` into `1 byte`, data lost is a normal thing in this way.